# Building a slider for all posts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, slider

In the header of my website, I have a horizontal list of the 6 latest posts. Now I would like to add a "previous" button, which causes the content of this list to be replaced by the 6 posts before the ones that are currently displayed. The idea is that, if a user clicks "previous" often enough, he is able to thereby see all posts ever made.

Most of the tutorials for creating this always load ALL posts, and then simply stuff them into some jQuery-slider. However, since I have 100+ posts, this seems not the best approach (some users might actually never click "previous" at all so why waste resources loading them).

Could you please point me to a tutorial that explains how I can get the previous posts using php each time the "previous" button is clicked? (I'm using Wordpress btw)

---

*The problem was solved without any tutorial, just with the help of a few stackoverflow threads. Now I have an awesome Post-Slider :)*

Answer (score 1):

If you rely on php for that, you'll need to refresh the page each time. I think you really want an AJAX solution.

You can build a PHP web service that

1) accepts some variable, such as the ID of the lowest post currently displayed

2) outputs XML or JSON of the six posts prior to that

Then, on your page, `onclick` of your previous button, send the variable, accept the response, and place each post as needed. `.ajax` and `.load` are some jQuery methods to look into

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of the general concept, I am just looking for a tutorial that explains an actual implementation.

Comment: are there any pieces you're more/less comfortable with? Or do you want a whole end-to-end how-to? and are you using MySQL to hold your posts?

Comment: I am using Wordpress, which atm seems to be my main problem. I tried the following code:    

    $("#post-area").load("post-getter.php", {page: 1}, function(){
    });
which should work. However, Wordpress won't let me access the php-file that way (404).

Apart from this problem, in my post-getter.php I only need to echo out the posts and that should do it, right?

Comment: I think you can take out the , function(){} for brevity...and unfortunately I don't use WP...is post-getter native to that, or something you built? is it in the same folder as the page asking for it? sounds like you're quite close

Comment: post-getter.php is the php-file I wrote for getting the posts from the DB based on the page-parameter (as you suggested). So this file uses the native Wordpress-functions). I know that this file works, because when I do <?php include("post-getter.php") it works. So it seems to be some WP security thingy or such that doesn't allow me to use it with load("post-getter.php").

Comment: Ok, so now the load php-file part works. But how can I access the value of the page-parameter in post-getter.php? I've tried $page = $_GET['page']; that doesn't do anything.

Comment: change that to `$_POST['page']` since you posted the variable...or to `$_REQUEST['page']` which will give you flexibility to use GET or POST going forward...if you had done `post-getter.php?page=1` then GET would have worked

Comment: Thank you! It works :). Now I have a prev- and a next-button that both work by incrementing a page-counter.

Comment: Now I'll have to work out how to not show the next-button on the last page, i.e. I need to somehow get the maximum number of pages from my php-file?
Also, wouldn't it be best to append the new posts to the list of the current posts rather then just replacing the content of the div? Cause the user might go back again and then I'd repeat the db-access that I've done before already?

Comment: I don't know the syntax of the slider code, but you do have a point about appending, (or prepending depending on which direction you're going). For the button you _could_ instead of returning the posts directly from your php, return a JSON array, of 1) the posts and 2) whether there is more to be retrieved. Then you'd convert the posts into the html and pre/append, and do some IF test on that other piece of data

Comment: I've done all the appending and it works like a charm :) The only thing left is determining the maximum number of pages. In my php-file I echo out a non-visible <div id="max_pages" title="$max_page"></div>. Now the problem is the jQuery. For some reason it doesn't recognise this div initially. Even though  $("div#max_page").attr("title") is placed after load() in the code, it returns "undefined". When I click next, the number is correct though? I'm assuming the problem is that the div was created by the php code and hence hasn't been there on document ready... ?

Comment: do you know that value (max_page) on first load? could you put in there so that it is always there? otherwise, there is the `.live` jQuery method...I'm a little rusty on it, but I recall using that to manipulate things that had been added via AJAX

Comment: Turns out you have to use the callback of .load() as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401851/accessing-elements-which-have-been-added-to-the-dom-via-file-loaded-using-load. Also I managed to get a nice sliding effect with the help of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391418/fadeout-load-new-content-fadein-slide. Thanks so much for your help. I have been procrastinating this forever, and now I finally have an  awesome Post-Slider! :)

Comment: Now that it all works, I found one minor flaw. Since I'm doing everything wthin `$(document).ready(function() {                        ... });` the slider does not load before the whole page has loaded. Is there a way to make it load as soon as the necessary divs are loaded (i.e. once the header - where the slider is placed - is loaded, but before the rest of the page is loaded)?

Comment: I _think_ you could just add another <script> with the inital loading functions right after the divs you mean so it runs before onReady