# fadeout, load new content, fadein --> slide

Tags: jquery, load, fade, slide

I am currently fading out the content of a div, replacing it with new content, and then fading it in again as follows:

```
area.fadeOut('400').load("file.php", 
    function(){
        $(this).fadeIn('400');
    }
);
```

First of all, is this chained correctly?

Secondly, I would like to replace the fading-in by sliding-in from the right, if that was possible (would need to slide the old content to the left)? How could that be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to point out that `fadeIn` & `fadeOut` are part of jQuery Core. Do you have jQuery UI loaded in? If not, you'll need it for the version of show used in other answers.

Also, you already have the area variable, so there's no need to re-instance with `S(this)`. It slows down the experience the more you do it.

Try this:

```
var newArea = area.clone().css("display", "none").insertAfter(area);
newArea.load("file.php", function() {
    area.hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, 400, function() {
        area.remove();
        area = newArea;
    });
    newArea.show("slide", {direction:"left"}, 400);

});
```

It should load into a hidden element then slide in from the right side as the original element slide to the left.

EDIT: Since it seems you're looking for something a little different, I'm updating the code.

Comment: Do I need UI for your version too? As with the others: the code leads to display: none ?

Comment: Yes, it's not terribly difficult to do what you want without the jQuery UI library, but it's up to you what you want to do. The main difference is that you'd preset some css and use the 'animate' method instead of the 'show' method.

Comment: Well, I just want to have the old content sliding out to the left with the new content sliding in from the right. I'd prefer not to include it if it's not really necessary. Thank you for the hint with the $(this)!

Comment: WARNING! If you don't add in the jQuery UI libraries, the 'show' method will fail. The HTML will stay hidden.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I experienced! With the UI the code works, however that is not really what I had in mind. Isn't it possible to have the sliding-out and -in occur simultaneously? (Like they do it in non-ajax sliders)

Comment: Like a ticker?
You'll definitely need some more complex code. What you'll need to do is start with the 'load' method. The old HTML will need to be hidden when you show the new content.

Comment: Like here http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html (click on previous/next below the big box). The previous one slides out, while the new one slides in. Can't be that hard?

Comment: Thank you for the code-update, so you are basically appending the new content to the old one? The problem here is that this is part of a slider, so the more I click "show more", the longer the list of appended posts gets. And they are not hidden!?

Comment: So I am assuming once the new content div is at the right position, it needs to become the 'new old content div'?

Comment: If you start with one set of content and move on to the next without ever needing to show the old content, then replace the old 'area' with 'newArea' variable make sure you remove the original area. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The updated answer doesn't do the trick for me. But since your answers are really helpful, here's the whole story: I'm building a recent-posts-slider and load(...) loads 10 new posts into some area. I don't really know the best way of doing it, atm I'm just calling load everytime the previous-  or next-button is clicked. I think it would be better to only call load when next is clicked - and keep all the posts, such that when pevious is clicked again load does not have to be called again, instead it could simply slide back? Hope that makes sense to you ;)

Comment: Ok, so now I have implemented the logic that I've just explained. Now everything can be seen as list that needs to slide either to the left or to the right when the corresponding buttons are clicked, preferably without UI?

Comment: myDiv.animate({"scrollLeft": (width)},'duration'); does it for me :) :) :) Without UI.

Answer (score 0):

looks fine to me, just replace the call to `fadeIn()` with `$(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400);`

Comment: and remove the initial fadeOut I assume? Well that waits 400 and then slights it in, even though the sliding is way too fast to see it?

Comment: How can I modify the length of the actual sliding-effect?

Comment: @Ben, change the 400. For a question like that you really should just google `jquery slide` for the api

Comment: Well changing the 400 doesn't modify the length of the actual sliding effect. All it does is change the duration before the effect is applied!? My main question here is the correct chaining of all the effects + the load, and that apparently isn't that simple!?

Answer (score 0):

```
area.fadeOut('400', function() {
    $(this).load("file.php", function() {
            $(this).show("slide", {direction:"left"}, 400);
    });
});
```

I think you need to call `load` like this because it might not wait for `fadeOut` to finish.

Comment: Your brackets are not properly closed. This code does not make the content visible.

Comment: The visibility is still none?

Comment: What is area? Is it a variable that you have assigned as a selector? If not you need to use something like `$('#area')`. If that is not the problem, just do `$(this).show();` to see if there is a problem with the rest of the parameters.

Comment: Sorry Connor, var area = $('someDiv');