# Accessing elements which have been added to the DOM via file loaded using .load()

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-load

I am using jQuery .load() to load a php-file. This php-file echos out a new div. This div contains an attribute "title", whose value I need to get in my js-file.

```
// file.php
echo '<div id="max_page" title="' . $max_page . '"></div>';

// js
$("someElement").load("file.php");
var num = $("div#max_page").attr("title");
```

This results in num = "undefined". I am assuming the reason for this is that the div#max_page gets added to the DOM after the initial $(document).ready was performed and hence jQuery simply doesn't know of its existence. Is that right?

How can the problem be solved? (I tried experimenting with .live() but couldn't get it to work for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the `num` it hasn't been added to the DOM yet as the ajax hasn't finished loading the page into the DOM yet. Do it in the `complete` callback of `load`:

```
$("someElement").load("file.php",function(){
var num = $("div#max_page").attr("title");
});
```

Comment: I did as suggested and now I actually get the value of the attribute. However, its still weird. can I call functions below the var num = ... line?

Comment: @Ben functions that rely on the `num` to be assigned, no. You'll need to put that stuff in the callback function as well.

Comment: What I want to do is this: obj.totalPages = $("div#max_page").attr("title");
displayNumbers(obj); And that doesn't work. However, if I take all the code from displayNumbers() and copy it into the callback it does work. Is there any way arround the redundancy?

Comment: If you have `obj.totalPages = $("div#max_page").attr("title"); displayNumbers(obj);` inside the callback, it should work. Where is the rest of `obj` defined? Could you post a full copy of the relevant code in your script to jsfiddle or something?

Comment: It looks like its a problem with the obj. Cause if I change the function + call to `displayNumbers(obj, num)` and use `num` instead of `obj.totalPages` within the function, it does work. Very confusing. I'll try to find the relevant bits.

Comment: @Ben looks like you got some problems with where/how you are defining you are obj

Comment: So now that I've been over the whole code to get it into some nice pasteble format, it suddenly works! Dunno why, either caching or maybe I did change something. But it definitely works now using `obj.totalPages = $("div#max_page").attr("title"); displayNumbers(obj)` (with the original function). Thanks so much for your help (I don't have enough reputation points to upvote  yet, but it is definitely appreciated)!

Comment: @Ben glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

You're right on thinking that your timing is wrong :)

```
// js
$("someElement").load("file.php", function(){
    var num = $("div#max_page").attr("title");
    // here you can do with num whatever you need
});
```

The function passed as a second argument will be executed immediately after `file.php` is loaded into `someElement`, thus guaranteed that the title attribute will exist at this point.

Answer (score 0):

the file hasn't loaded when you set `num`.  use a callback.

```
$("someElement").load("file.php", function () {
   var num = $("div#max_page").attr("title");
});
```